# gdal polygonize can't create .gkpg file

Tags: gdal, polygonize, geopackage

I'm currently trying to take a .tif file and polygonize it, I can do this if the output file format is a .shp but when I try to make a .gkpg file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_polygonize.py", line 169, in <module>
    dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_filename )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataSource'
```

I am unsure as to why this is occurring as http://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.html says this is a possible file format.

As for the code I'm using:

```
call([sys.executable, 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdal_polygonize.py',infile.tif, '-f' ,'GKPG', outfile.gkpg])
```

Comment: I think gdal_polygonize is used to transform a raster to a vector file, and a .shp is an ogr format for a vector file

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I just realised that I've written .shp as the input file, it's actually a .tif input file. I have amended the question to reflect this correction

Comment: A test from the command line of OSGeo4W is successful `gdal_polygonize -f gpkg test.tif polygonize.gpkg Creating output polygonize.gpkg of format gpkg.`

Comment: @Yjelza in your command you are using `GKPG` instead of `GPKG`

Comment: Hi, this has worked indeed, thank you very much! Also, this seems rather slow at building the file?

Comment: If the script is inserting polygons one by one it will be for sure slow with SQLite based formats. For example ogr2ogr by default collects 20000 inserts into one transaction. I do not know how gdal_polygonize deals with transactions.

Comment: Hmmm that is annoying, is there any way around this? I am trying to find an alternative to .shp files because I often have to exceed the 2GB file limit.

Comment: First try to confirm that it really happens. If you can confirm that script is making one-row transactions, write a mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if someone knows how to improve the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Hicham Zourhi, I had a spelling mistake in my code.

The format should be GPKG and not GKPG.